# Kibana geojson upload hangs on creating index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

When uploading a geojson file into a map, Kibana hangs indefinitely on "Writing to index".

It's the same issue as in this fixed bug: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/40102

I have Kibana v7.6.1, so it should be fixed in this version.

The index I want to use is one of these (I think this is the website I got it from): https://datamillnorth.org/dataset/ons-ward-boundaries

The geojson file is only 1.7 MB. I've had the same problem with all the other geojson files I've tried. I haven't successfully uploaded any geojson files.

If I look in Index Management, the index is present, but it doesn't come up as an option when I make a new map and try to add an index layer.

Answer (score 0):

Bug report on Kibana: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/61794

It relates to an elastic search and it's because the file I was using is bad.

I used the mapshaper CLI to fix the file: https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Introduction-to-the-Command-Line-Tool

```
mapshaper -i leeds.geojson -clean -o leeds_fixed.geojson
```

This originally didn't work with the file I had. I got a different version of the file from a different website (https://martinjc.github.io/UK-GeoJSON/), and ran the above CLI, and it fixed the problem in Kibana.